# Why Stack Overflow Error when dirty editor is closed with or without saving?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have this stack overflow exception when I click on "do not save" or "save" button on a dirty editor after trying to close it. The editor contains a composite with OpenGL rendering using JOGL/jzy3D.

JOGL 2.3.2,
Jzy3D 2.0,
Mac OSX14,
Eclipse 4.19

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2021-10-28 20:11:00.400
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSThread.isMainThread(NSThread.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5992)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.setNeedsDisplay(Widget.java:1904)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:6300)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSView.setNeedsDisplay(NSView.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.redraw(Control.java:2874)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelectionBackground(CTabFolder.java:3271)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelectionBackground(CTabFolder.java:3409)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.properties.custom.CSSPropertySelectedTabsSWTHandler.applyCSSProperty(CSSPropertySelectedTabsSWTHandler.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.properties.AbstractCSSPropertySWTHandler.applyCSSProperty(AbstractCSSPropertySWTHandler.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.engine.AbstractCSSEngine.applyCSSProperty(AbstractCSSEngine.java:746)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.engine.AbstractCSSEngine.applyStyleDeclaration(AbstractCSSEngine.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.engine.AbstractCSSEngine.applyStyles(AbstractCSSEngine.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.engine.AbstractCSSEngine.applyStyles(AbstractCSSEngine.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngine.applyStyles(ThemeEngine.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.setClassnameAndId(PartRenderingEngine.java:1322)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.setCSSInfo(SWTPartRenderer.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.updateNonFocusState(WBWRenderer.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.lambda$6(WBWRenderer.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4441)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1512)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1535)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1516)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowDidResignKey(Shell.java:2378)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:6167)
    at jogamp.newt.driver.macosx.WindowDriver.requestFocus0(Native Method)
    at jogamp.newt.driver.macosx.WindowDriver.access$700(WindowDriver.java:61)
    at jogamp.newt.driver.macosx.WindowDriver$5.run(WindowDriver.java:308)
    at jogamp.nativewindow.macosx.OSXUtil.RunOnMainThread(OSXUtil.java:267)
    at jogamp.newt.driver.macosx.WindowDriver.requestFocusImpl(WindowDriver.java:305)
    at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl$4.run(WindowImpl.java:2792)
    at jogamp.newt.DisplayImpl.runOnEDTIfAvail(DisplayImpl.java:450)
    at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.runOnEDTIfAvail(WindowImpl.java:2782)
    at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.requestFocus(WindowImpl.java:2824)
    at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.requestFocus(WindowImpl.java:2817)
    at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.requestFocus(WindowImpl.java:2812)
    at com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow.requestFocus(GLWindow.java:415)
    at com.jogamp.newt.swt.NewtCanvasSWT.requestFocusNEWTChild(NewtCanvasSWT.java:456)
    at com.jogamp.newt.swt.NewtCanvasSWT.forceFocus(NewtCanvasSWT.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setFocus(Control.java:3880)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1104)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer$1.setFocus(ContributedPartRenderer.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setFocus(CTabFolder.java:2681)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowDidBecomeKey(Shell.java:2316)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:6171)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.becomeKeyWindow(Widget.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.becomeKeyWindow(Shell.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5890)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(NSWindow.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.makeKeyAndOrderFront(Shell.java:1337)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setActive(Shell.java:1596)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.bringToTop(Shell.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.forceFocus(Control.java:1464)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setFocus(Control.java:3880)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1104)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowDidBecomeKey(Shell.java:2316)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:6171)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.becomeKeyWindow(Widget.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.becomeKeyWindow(Shell.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5890)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(NSWindow.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.makeKeyAndOrderFront(Shell.java:1337)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setActive(Shell.java:1596)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.bringToTop(Shell.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.forceFocus(Control.java:1464)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setFocus(Control.java:3880)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1104)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowDidBecomeKey(Shell.java:2316)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:6171)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.becomeKeyWindow(Widget.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.becomeKeyWindow(Shell.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5890)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(NSWindow.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.makeKeyAndOrderFront(Shell.java:1337)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setActive(Shell.java:1596)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.bringToTop(Shell.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.forceFocus(Control.java:1464)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setFocus(Control.java:3880)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1104)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowDidBecomeKey(Shell.java:2316)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:6171)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.becomeKeyWindow(Widget.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.becomeKeyWindow(Shell.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5890)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(NSWindow.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.makeKeyAndOrderFront(Shell.java:1337)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setActive(Shell.java:1596)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.bringToTop(Shell.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.forceFocus(Control.java:1464)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setFocus(Control.java:3880)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1104)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowDidBecomeKey(Shell.java:2316)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:6171)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.becomeKeyWindow(Widget.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.becomeKeyWindow(Shell.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5890)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(NSWindow.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.makeKeyAndOrderFront(Shell.java:1337)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setActive(Shell.java:1596)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.bringToTop(Shell.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.forceFocus(Control.java:1464)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setFocus(Control.java:3880)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1104)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowDidBecomeKey(Shell.java:2316)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:6171)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.becomeKeyWindow(Widget.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.becomeKeyWindow(Shell.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5890)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(NSWindow.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.makeKeyAndOrderFront(Shell.java:1337)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setActive(Shell.java:1596)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.bringToTop(Shell.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.forceFocus(Control.java:1464)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setFocus(Control.java:3880)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1104)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowDidBecomeKey(Shell.java:2316)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:6171)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.becomeKeyWindow(Widget.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.becomeKeyWindow(Shell.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5890)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(NSWindow.java:201)

....
```

The stack trace does not go through any of my RCP App code line and I cannot debug to see where is my error. As far as I understand it is a focus endless loop !

I wrote handler for the save case and if I click on the save button/menu before closing the editor, I do not have this error.

Have you ever seen this behavior ? Any ideas ?
Thks

Comment: What if you will try to not create a composite with OpenGL, will you have the same error? Please also note that SWT code from your trace is MacOS-specific.

Comment: No there no problem with standard composite in editor parts. It occurs only with an OpenGL composite. And yes it is specific to MacOSX.

Comment: There is an entry to this loop that is the most valuable. I suspect the problem may be somethere around abstract method WorkbenchPart#setFocus that is somehow implemented in your EditorPart

Comment: In this setfocus method i just force the focus on a SWT List : if(trialsListViewer != null) trialsListViewer.getList().setFocus();

Comment: I recommend to decrease you actual code to minimal example where problem is repeatable and submit it to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform